# L2 Norm Inequality

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, holder-inequality

Let $f_1,f_2,f_3:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ be measurable, bounded, and compactly supported. Prove that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}f_1(y,z)f_2(x,z)f_3(x,y)d(x,y,z)\le\lVert f_1\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}\lVert f_2\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}\lVert f_3\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}$$ By Tonelli's Theorem and Cauchy, \begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}f_1(y,z)f_2(x,z)f_3(x,y)d(x,y,z) &=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\left(f_1(y,z)\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_2(x,z)f_3(x,y)dx\right)d(y,z)\\
&\le\sqrt{\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f_1^2(y,z)d(y,z)\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_2(x,z)f_3(x,y)dx\right)^2d(y,z)} \\
&\le\lVert f_1\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}\sqrt{\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_2^2(x,z)f_3^2(x,y)dx\right)d(y,z)} \\
&=\Vert f_1\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}\sqrt{\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}f_2^2(x,z)f_3^2(x,y)d(x,y,z)} \\
&=\lVert f_1\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}\sqrt{\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\left(f_2^2(x,z)\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_3^2(x,y)dy\right)d(x,z)} \\
&\le\lVert f_1\rVert_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}\sqrt[4]{\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f_2^4(x,z)d(x,z)\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_3^2(x,y)dy\right)^2d(x,z)}
\end{align}
 As you can see, this doesn't seem to be going anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&\int f_{1}(y,z)f_{2}(x,z)f_{3}(x,y)dxdydz\\
&=\int f_{1}(y,z)f_{2}(x,z)dz f_{3}(x,y)dxdy\\
&\leq\int\left(\int f_{1}(y,z)^{2}dz\right)^{1/2}\left(\int f_{2}(x,z)^{2}dz\right)^{1/2}f_{3}(x,y)dxdy\\
&\leq\left(\int\left(\int f_{1}(y,z)^{2}dz\right)\left(\int f_{2}(x,z)^{2}dz\right)dxdy\right)^{1/2}\left(\int f_{3}(x,y)^{2}dxdy\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\left(\int f_{1}(y,z)^{2}dydz\right)^{1/2}\left(\int f_{2}(x,z)^{2}dxdz\right)^{1/2}\left(\int f_{3}(x,y)^{2}dxdy\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\|f_{1}\|_{L^{2}}\|f_{2}\|_{L^{2}}\|f_{3}\|_{L^{2}}.
\end{align*}